# Django dynamic field casting when annotate

Tags: django, django-models

Lets say I want to save this data in to db:

```
{
        "fields": [
            {
                "field_type": "number",
                "name": "field_1",
                "value": 8223,
            },
            {
                "field_type": "string",
                "name": "field_2",
                "value": "demo"
              
            },
            {
                "field_type": "bool",
                "name": "field_3",
                "value": true
              
            }
        ],
        "blockchain_id": 47,
        "name": "event",
        "block_number": 3916102,
    }
```

Here `value` is dynamic based on `field_type` value. Here is my models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    blockchain_id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    block_number = models.IntegerField()
    fields = models.ManyToManyField(EventField)

class EventField(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('number', 'Number'),
        ('string', 'String'),
        ('bool', 'Boolean'),
    )
    field_type = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I am saving dynamic `value` as Character (you can suggest something better). Then when I am returing those values I want to cast based on `field_type` value. So far here is my query:

```
Event.objects.filter(id=_id).annotate(fields_value=Case(
            When(fields__field_type='number', then=Cast('fields__value', output_field=models.IntegerField())),
            When(fields__field_type='string', then=Cast('fields__value', output_field=models.CharField())),
            When(fields__field_type='bool', then=Cast('fields__value', output_field=models.BooleanField())),
            output_field=Case(When(fields__field_type='number', then=models.IntegerField()))))
```

Now I am gettings this error message `Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field` .Maybe I am missing something. How can I return value with casting based on field_type ?

Comment: You can not work with such dynamic casting,s ince that means that for the same column there can be multiple types. You will need to do the conversion at the Django/Python layer: SQL is *strongly typed*.

Answer (score 0):

You can not work with such dynamic casting: for SQL each column has a specific type and all records use the same type for that column.

You will need to do this at the Django/Python layer, for example with:

```
class EventField(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('number', 'Number'),
        ('string', 'String'),
        ('bool', 'Boolean'),
    )
    field_type = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @property
    def typed_value(self):
        if self.field_type == 'number':
            return int(self.value)
        if self.field_type == 'string':
            return self.value
        if self.field_type == 'bool':
            return self.value.casefold() == 'true'
        raise ValueError('Invalid field type.')
```

You can then inspec the value with `my_event_field.typed_value`.